# issue setting up a download link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Very new to rails, so hopefully this is a simple fix. I am trying to set up a link to download a file I store in my website.  Here is my download function:

controller

```
  def download  
    send_file @exam.photo.path, :type => @exam.photo_content_type, :filename => @exam.permalink 
  end
```

My routes.rb

```
  resources :exams do
    member do
      get :download
   end
end
```

and my view

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_exam_path(@exam.photo.path) %>
```

I use `paperclip` to upload the image.  I can display it, but I cannot download.  Here is my error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/exams/Users/R45/Programming/rails_projects/oldV_rails_project/public/system/exams/photos/000/000/016/original/Chapter.jpg/download"
```

Which seems to "tac-on" /download at the of my image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route is wrong in your link. Try:

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_exam_path(@exam) %>
```

However since the error message suggests the photo of the exam is in the public path, it might be easiest to simply href the photo directly:

```
<%= link_to "Download", @exam.photo.path %>
```